# How Can Formatting Arabic Name of Date ar-AR or en-EN in SAP Crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, formula

How can I display Arabic name of day ar-AR from a date in Formula sap crystal report in C#?

like this code from C# get Hijri Date and Name In arabic ar-AR:

```
Hejra_label.Text = HijraDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy" + " " + "MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA"));
```